# Accessing Specific Pixels (Corresponding to Facial Points) with Kinect 1.5

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, kinect, pixel, rgba

I've been researching the Kinect API and programming with the new SDK (1.5) for a few weeks now, and I'm basically trying to find where the eyes are in each image streamed from the Kinect sensor. I then want to get the RGB values for the pixels that make up the eyes. Though some variables, like pFaceModel2DPoint and pPts2D (both in Visualize.cpp), claim to store the x,y values for all 86 points that make up the face in the colorImage (of type IFTImage*), I have tested and re-tested these variables but cannot access worthwhile data from these variables.

Furthermore, even if these x,y values corresponding to the eyes were correct for the given image, I cannot find out how to access the RGB values for each pixel desired. I know the macro (FTIMAGEFORMAT_UINT8_B8G8R8A8) to find the format in which the pixel data is stored, and I know that byte* pixels = colorImage->GetBuffer() will give the buffer stream for the current image streaming from the Kinect, but doing something as simple as pixels[rowNum*num_cols_per_row + colNum] = [...] inside of a for loop does not yield anything useful.

I've been really discouraged and disappointed that I cannot get this working, but I have searched through so many sites and search engines for any resolution to a problem close to mine and have found nothing. I wrote my own code several times using OpenCV and the Kinect, just the Kinect itself, and modifications of the MultiFace sample from the SDK. (These variables and functions listed above are from the MultiFace sample.) Any help would be extremely appreciated. Thank you!

Update: The Kinect API was unclear, hence my asking the question, but I have solved this problem after some trial and error. The image format is actually RGBX (formatted as BGRX), so elements 0-3 in the byte* correspond to pixel 0, elements 4-7 correspond to pixel 1, etc. Pretty simple; I had just gotten confused between the different methods of handling the image stream because there are a few GetBuffer-type calls in the same header file. Hopefully this will help someone else!